# What is wrong with the argument that $\frac d{dx} \int_0^1 f(x)dx$ should always be $0$ for any $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

*What is wrong with the argument that $\frac d{dx} \int_0^1 f(x)dx$ should always be $0$ for any $f(x)$?*

My book used differentiation under the integral sign to evaluate an integral. The integral was $\int_0^1 \frac{x^a -1}{\log x}dx$. They differentiated it with respect to $a$ and wrote the derivative as 
$$\int_0^1 \frac d {da}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{\log x} \right )dx = \int_0^1 \frac {x^a \log x}{\log x}dx$$

They then went further and did some steps to arrive at the answer.

I find the differentiation problematic. From what I know, a definite integral is just a *number*. And the derivative of a number is $0$. So derivative of every definite integral should be $0$.

But apparently this is not the case. Even Wikipedia has an article on differentiation under the integral sign. So its obviously a thing.

My question is, what is wrong with my argument? What am I missing?

Comment: But $a$ there is a variable, you integrate a function that has another parameter appart from the integration variable.

Comment: $\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx$ is a constant, so its derivative is $0$. You're overloading the variable $x$ here. You are using $x$ both as a dummy variable of integration, as well as a free variable for differentiation. You can equivalently write the integrand as $f(y)\ dy$, which makes it clear that the integral is independent of $x$.

Comment: You recieved two answers to your question. Is there anything left that is unclear? If not, I advise you to accept one of the answers...

Comment: @5xum I was busy, so didn't get a chance to check them out. Done now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the fact that there are two variables in the expression $\frac{x^a-1}{\log x}$. There's $x$, and then there's $a$.

The expression

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^a-1}{\log x}\;dx$$

**is** independent of $x$, but it is **not** independent of $a$, and the derivative with respect to $a$ **could be non zero**.

Basically, you don't have $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$, you have $\int_0^1 f(x,a)dx$.

---

For example, take a look at what happens if $f(x,a)=a\cdot x$. In that case, $$\int_0^1 f(x,a)dx=\int_0^1 a\cdot x dx = \frac a2$$

meaning that $$\frac{d}{da}\int_0^1 a\cdot x dx = \frac{d}{da}(\frac a2)= \frac12\neq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not helpful and is source of confusion to write $\frac d{dx} \int_0^1 f(x)dx$. You should write this as $\frac d{dx} \int_{x'=0}^{x'=1} f(x')dx'$. Then you are taking $\frac{d}{d x}$ of a constant which is zero. However, you do have, $\frac d{dx} \int^{x'=x} f(x')dx'= f(x)$.

Comment: It's also a source of confusion if you write $x'$, as that reminds people of the derivative...